# How can I attract users' attention to my question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions

I am not getting as many visits as I'd like for one of my questions. What is the proper way to attract attention to my questions? How can I improve my questions on Stack Overflow so that they get a decent number of visits?

Answer (score 1):

You can offer a Bounty on your question to drag attention of other users. If you visit the FAQ section, you can see following details there ,

### What if I don’t get a good answer?

First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by offering a bounty.

The Otherway you can do it is Chat Room.

Comment: I have tried with bounty but did not get more views. It is expired now. Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951067/magento-product-flat-data-and-catalog-search-index-issue

Comment: @Anoop, did you try second option ?

Comment: You mean i can get more view by editing questions time to time.

Comment: I mean Chat room.

Comment: I tried this option too. but got less user in chat room. I will try it again.